Define value for multiple materials
I have an object with different materials mapped to different parts of its surface. But there are some parameters shared by all these materials that need to have the same value; e.g. roughness. At the moment, if I want to modify this roughness value, I have to do so in each material. Is there some way of setting a single value that they all can share?

You can create a custom property in the "object" tab of the object.
Configure it to type "float" and give it a name:


Then use it in the shader nodes. (There will be this initial work, but later you can just change the value of the property)


The best method is using node groups. Add a value node and press ctrl  + G

Inside the node group, you can edit socket name:

Then in the next material add existing node group using Shift  + A

The number next to the node group name will indicate that the same node group is used in different material.

Then you want to edit value, enter nodegroup by pressing Tab and change value inside:

